# Create Pivot from Column Values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a number of records for equipment contracts and need to display the total available days by year for each piece of equipment and contract.

For example, the table may contain multiple contracts spanning different periods for the same piece of equipment and I need to show how many days the equipment was available for each year.

The table structure looks like;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblContracts]
(
[ID]            [int]       NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[EquipmentId]       [int]       NOT NULL,
[ContractTypeId]    [int]       NOT NULL,
[FromDt]        [datetime]  NOT NULL,
[SpudDt]        [datetime]  NULL,
[ToDt]          [datetime]  NOT NULL
)
```

The result I need would look like;

```
EquipmentId  2012  2013  2014  2015
1             120   365   180    30
```

I have a function that, given the Equipment ID and Year, will return the total number of days the equipment was available for the specified year however, except for creating some dynamic SQL, I'm not sure how to return the data in the format required.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can refer this below link for Pivot with Dynamic column values.

Link :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284251/another-pivot-with-dynamic-fields

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague.  For instance, what does available mean?  What is the function?

This following may do what you need:

```
select EquipmentId,
       sum(MyFunc(EquipmentId, 2012)) as [2012],
       sum(MyFunc(EquipmentId, 2013)) as [2013],
       sum(MyFunc(EquipmentId, 2014)) as [2014],
       sum(MyFunc(EquipmentId, 2015)) as [2015]
from tblContracts c
group by EquipmentId;
```

Comment: "Available" is the number of days the equipment is available for use in the given year.  For example; if there was only 1 contract for the period 25 Dec 2013 to 14 Jan 2014 the equipment is available for 6 days in 2013 and 15 days in 2014.  If however there was a 2nd contract for the same equipment record for the period 1 Feb 2014 to 10 Feb 2014 then the equipment is available for 26 days in 2104.
The function is used to calculate these values.

Comment: The query needs to cater for additional years as additional contracts are added (we contract equipment in advance by as much as 6-7 years) so anything hard coded is not suitable.

Comment: No doubts you hv to create dynamic sql.Do it later on .
In gordon query,MyFunc with year you can find first and last day of year .
Then query and sum between first and last day that year .Let the function return sum value so that you don't hv use group by in main function .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to use dynamic SQL to resolve the issue though it does seem to be a pity there is no pivot like function that perform this relatively simple requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Ray Brack this one will work, I got **correct answer with your table structure**.
Note that you should **subtract 366** in case of **Leap Year**.

```
   SELECT T.EquipmentId,
       365 - T.[2013] AS [2013],
       365 - T.[2014] AS [2014],
       365 - T.[2015] AS [2015]
   FROM   (SELECT EquipmentId,
           [2013],
           [2014],
           [2015]
    FROM   (SELECT EquipmentId,
                   Datepart(Year, ToDt)        AS Yr,
                   Datediff(Day, FromDt, ToDt) AS Diff
            FROM   tblContracts
            ) X PIVOT 
            ( Sum(Diff)
                 FOR Yr IN([2013],
                           [2014],
                           [2015]) 
            )P
   )T
```

Result

```
    --------------------------------------------
    EquipmentId |    2013   |   2014  | 2015
    --------------------------------------------
    1           |    351    |   337   | 337
```